# .NET Entity Framework - Using .Contains() to find a byte value in a Where expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am building an IQueryable based on parameters I get from the user. One of those parameters is a multi-select and I need to retrieve records that contain any of the selected values.

The code that deals with that is:

`var ids = parameters.DeliveryID.ToArray();
courses = courses.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.CourseDeliveryID));`

In the above code:
1. ids - is a byte array and I make sure it has multiple values before calling Contains().
2. c.CourseDeliveryID - that's a byte value.

In the database I store CourseDeliveryID as tinyint (SQL Server 2008).

Compilation is just fine.

When I run the code I get the following ArgumentException:

`DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.

Parameter name: input`

I found the documentation for that exception here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.commandtrees.expressionbuilder.dbexpressionbuilder.bindas.aspx

While trying to solve the problem I found that if I use the same code on shorts, ints or longs I don't have any problem.

I'm in touch with Microsoft about it since yesterday and will update when I know more, but in the meantime I figured I'd throw it also here to get more advises if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Open up your generated edmx entity framework file and check out what data type CourseDeliveryID got mapped to.  Maybe it didn't correctly recognize tinyint as byte.

Comment: @Milimetric - Thanks heaps for the tip, but it didn't help.. I checked the XML definition file and the property is mapped properly and defined as byte: <Property Name="CourseDeliveryID" Type="Byte" Nullable="false" />.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your error in LINQPad, and found that using a `List<byte>` instead of a `byte[]` would work:

```
// byte[] ids = new byte[] { 1, 64 };  <== causes ArgumentException
List<byte> ids = new List<byte> { 1, 64};

var c = Courses.Where (co => ids.Contains(co.CourseDeliveryId));
```

will generate the following sql and return results:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[CourseId] AS [CourseId], 
[Extent1].[CourseName] AS [CourseName], 
[Extent1].[CourseDeliveryId] AS [CourseDeliveryId]
FROM [dbo].[Courses] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[CourseDeliveryId] IN (1,64)
```

It's also interesting that using an `int[]` or `short[]` would also work, producing this sql:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[CourseId] AS [CourseId], 
[Extent1].[CourseName] AS [CourseName], 
[Extent1].[CourseDeliveryId] AS [CourseDeliveryId]
FROM [dbo].[Courses] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (1 =  CAST( [Extent1].[CourseDeliveryId] AS int)) OR (64 =  CAST( [Extent1].[CourseDeliveryId] AS int))
```

but using a `byte[]` causes an exception.  I can only guess that the SQL Server EF provider is trying to treat `byte[]` in some special way, resulting in this exception.

Comment: Aha! Ok. first of all - thanks so much!! So that's kind of a workaround, but it's supported and it works, so I guess we're good! As I said earlier I am in touch with Microsoft. I will send them also this thread and see what they think. It does smell like a bug, but who knows.. Thanks again!

Comment: @justabuzz, you're welcome; definitely looks like a bug to me.

Comment: It's possible byte[] is going through another code path as it is the type used for varbinary, timestamp etc.

Comment: DamienG is totally right. This is an issue we have in EF originated int he fact that we map byte[] to binary columns in the databse, so when we see the byte[] in this expression we don't handle it correctly. We already have a fix for EF vNext. Thanks.

Comment: This issue is still present in the last version of EF 5 and maybe in EF 6. I haven't been back to look at EF 6.

Comment: FYI: Issue still present in EF 6.1.0

Answer (score 2):

Although using different containers solve the issue, you do not have to change the container type.
All you need to do is assign it to IEnumerable:

```
IEnumerable<byte> ids = parameters.DeliveryID.ToArray();
courses = courses.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.CourseDeliveryID));
```

(In this specific case you can just use ToList() instead of ToArray() but in the general case if you get the byte array and do not want to rebuild it as a list this will do)