# Using an array of enumeration values in a where clause with Entity Framework 5

Tags: entity-framework, enums, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I'm using EF 5. My Entity has an property called Status which is an enum of type MyEntityStatus.

I need to do a query where I return all entities that have any of a list of statuses.

My basic code is as follows:

```
var statusArray = new MyEntityStatus[]{MyEntityStatus.Status1, MyEntityStatus.Status2};
var results = myDataContext.MyEntities..Where(e => statusArray.Contains(e.Status)).ToArray();
```

Code compiles, but EF returns the following error:

```
The type 'MyEntityStatus' does not match the EDM enumeration type 'MyEntityStatus' or its underlying type 'Byte'.
```

If I try to just use an array of bytes rather than the explicit enum type, I get the following error:

```
DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried Contains() instead of Any()?

Comment: Just tried it. Will update the question with a clarification.

Comment: try to cast to int before contains: e => statusArray.Cast<int>().Contains...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching from Any() to Contains() got me part of the way there, but the final solution required using a List rather than a byte[].

Here is the final code that works:

```
var statusArray = (new MyEntityStatus[]{MyEntityStatus.Status1, MyEntityStatus.Status2}).Cast<byte>().ToList();
var results = myDataContext.MyEntities..Where(e => statusArray.Contains((byte)e.Status)).ToArray();
```

Apparently, EF treats a List differently from byte[].

See: [.NET Entity Framework - Using .Contains() to find a byte value in a Where expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627670/net-entity-framework-using-contains-to-find-a-byte-value-in-a-where-expres)