# Linq expression (containing OR) incorrectly calculating WHERE clause?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a strange situation, I can not find a way why Linq 2 entities query is not returning results.

First query **is** returning results, but second is not returning results.

```
summaryData = db.PromoSummary.Where(x => x.Month == state.OldPromoStart.Month).ToList();
summaryData = db.PromoSummary.Where(x => (x.Month == state.OldPromoStart.Month) | (x.Month == state.OldPromoEndMonthMax)).ToList();
```

if "A" is true, then "A or B" should also be true... (in this case first statement is true, so it should return results regardless of the second statement, right?)

P.S. db is DbContext, PromoSummary is DbSet

**Any ideas what I am doing wrong?**

### EDIT

this PromoSummary DbSet has rows with Month==9, but no rows where Month == 10. I changed | to ||, but the result is the same - first query returns result, but second query returns 0 records...

```
summaryData = db.PromoSummary.Where(x => x.Month == 9).ToList();
summaryData = db.PromoSummary.Where(x => (x.Month == 9) || (x.Month == 10)).ToList();
```

### EDIT #2

I suppose this is what Andrew suggested... why is that "Is not null" checking?
P.S. in database Month property is called SummaryMonth (defined with Fluent api) and one more thing - this property is of type **byte**

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId], 
[Extent1].[SummaryYear] AS [SummaryYear], 
[Extent1].[SummaryMonth] AS [SummaryMonth], 
[Extent1].[ThemeId] AS [ThemeId], 
[Extent1].[CurrentStateId] AS [CurrentStateId]
FROM [PromotionSummary] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ((9 = ( CAST( [Extent1].[SummaryMonth] AS int))) 
         AND ( CAST( [Extent1].[SummaryMonth] AS int) IS NOT NULL)) 
   OR ((10 = ( CAST( [Extent1].[SummaryMonth] AS int))) 
         AND ( CAST( [Extent1].[SummaryMonth] AS int) IS NOT NULL))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `||` instead of bitwise or `|`

For your second update, try using following code:

```
List<byte> months = new List<byte> {9, 10};

summaryData = db.PromoSummary.Where(x => months.Contains(x.Month)).ToList();
```

Comment: can you execute second query without executing first one? are the results different?

Comment: what is the command text generated from second query? can you look into your ObjectQuery?

Comment: please see the second edit - I took that query from debug -> var q = db.PromoSummary.Where(x => (x.Month == 9) || (x.Month == 10)); //and then copied q.InternalQuery

Comment: can you have a look at the query generated once again when you use something like `x.Month == (byte)9`...btw, I'd consider using int value type instead of byte

Comment: hmmm... strangely enough, but this line -> var q = db.PromoSummary.Where(x => (x.Month == (byte)9) || (x.Month == (byte)10)); //produced exactly the same query... but I will try what happens if I change byte to int (although it's waste of space to spend 4 bytes for value that ranges from 1 to 12...)

Comment: could you please try query from edit of my answer? your provider is having some troubles with handling byte parameters probably. or there's some issue within Entity Framework itself...see last comment to accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627670/net-entity-framework-using-contains-to-find-a-byte-value-in-a-where-expres

Answer (score 2):

You should use `||` operator instead of the `|`:

```
summaryData = db.PromoSummary.Where(x => (x.Month == state.OldPromoStart.Month) || (x.Month == state.OldPromoEndMonthMax)).ToList();
```

The `|` operator is a binary `OR`, but the `||` is a logical one.

Answer (score 1):

Because your OR is [Binary OR](http://www.xcprod.com/titan/XCSB-DOC/binary_or.html)

You should write like:

```
db.PromoSummary.Where(x => (x.Month == state.OldPromoStart.Month) 
       || (x.Month == state.OldPromoEndMonthMax)).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

Considering that this *may be* SQL driver issue, you may try to do something like this. 
`LINQ` is known for defered execution, so you may write:

```
var first =  db.PromoSummary.Where(x => (x.Month == state.OldPromoStart.Month));
var second=  db.PromoSummary.Where(x => (x.Month == state.OldPromoEndMonthMax));

first.AddRange(second);     
return first.FirstOrDefault();
```

This *should* generate `SQL` you are searching for, so produce also desirable result.

Comment: Do you connect to MS Sql Server ?

Comment: No acctually it's VistaDB, should it matter?

Comment: You **probabbly** (bold) have a driver "problem", that can not translate your query into valid SQL.

Comment: guys, let the OP have a look at CommandText generated, next call ToTraceString() to have a look at actual transact sql

Comment: Please take a look, I added SQL statement in my second edit with some comments